# filter data from an array - php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array with the friends data including their name, id, gender. I want to extract the data from array which have opposite gender.
For example -
My gender is "Male"

Returned data -

```
[118]=> object(stdClass)#121 (3) {
    ["name"]=> string(9) "Rawa Su" 
    ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" 
    ["id"]=> string(15) "1000019100" 
} 
[119]=> object(stdClass)#122 (3) {
    ["name"]=> string(11) "Anil Gaj" 
    ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" 
    ["id"]=> string(15) "1000034656" 
} 
[120]=> object(stdClass)#123 (3) {
    ["name"]=> string(13) "Ankur Tri" 
    ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" 
    ["id"]=> string(15) "1000022271" 
} 
[121]=> object(stdClass)#124 (3) {
    ["name"]=> string(13) "Chuck Ell" 
    ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" 
    ["id"]=> string(15) "10000185038" 
} 
[122]=> object(stdClass)#125 (3) {
    ["name"]=> string(15) "Madhuri Tat" 
    ["gender"]=> string(6) "female" 
    ["id"]=> string(15) "1000880932" 
}
```

Now i want to randomly fetch the data which have gender =  female. I don't have any clue how this can be done. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay lets say your array with all of the data is named $data:

```
$res = array();
foreach($data as $person) {
     if(strcasecmp($person['gender'], 'female') == 0)
          $res[] = $person;
}
```

Now you have a new array called $res which contains all females.

Nevertheless, i would filter the raw data during the sql fetch from the database,
this should be the same effort and give more performance in a long time view.

If you now want to have one of the females randomly, do something like this:

```
$number_of_persons = count($res);
$random_female = $res[rand(0, $number_of_persons-1)];
```

Why -1?

Arrays start at index 0, so you need a -1 at the total amount of persons.

Comment: Superb brother ! Thank you so much. God bless you :)